# Can Functor instance be declared with additional type restriction for function

Tags: frege

I'm working on porting GHC/Arr.hs into Frege.

Array is defined:

```
data Array i e = Array{u,l::i,n::Int,elems::(JArray e)}
```

There is function:

```
amap :: (Ix i, ArrayElem e) => (a -> b) -> Array i a -> Array i b
```

Now, I don't know how to define `Functor` instance for it, because

```
instance (Ix i) => Functor (Array i) where
    fmap = amap
```

But compiler complains that inferred type is more constrained that expected, what seems true. Can I make `Array` an functor with restrction for functions `ArrayElem -> ArrayElem`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

If you base `Array` on `JArray` and want a functor instance, you must not use any functions that arise the ArrayElem (or any other additional) context.

Another way to say this is that you cannot base `Array` on type safe java  arrays, but must deal with java arrays of type `Object[]`. Because, as you have without doubt noted, the `ArrayElem` type class is just a trick to be able to provide the correct java type on creation of a java array. This is, of course, important for interfacing with Java and for performance reasons.

Note that there is another problem with type safe java arrays. Let's say we want to make an array of `Double` (but the same argument holds for any other element type). AFAIK, Haskell mandates that Arrays elements must be lazy. Hence we really cannot use the java type `double[]` (to which `JArray Double` would be the Frege counterpart) to model it. Because, if we would do this, every array element would have to be evaluated as soon as it is set.

For this reason, I suggest you use some general custom array element type, like

```
data AElem a = AE () a 
mkAE = A () 
unAE (AE _ x) = x
derive ArrayElement AElem
```

and change your definition:

```
data Array i e = Array{u,l::i,n::Int,elems::(JArray (AElem e))}
```

Now, your functor instance can be written, because the ArrayElem constraint does not arise, because when you access the `elems` array, the compiler knows that you have `AElem` elements and can and will supply the correct instance.

In addition, construction of `AElem`s and usage of `AElem`s as actual array elements does *not* impose strictness on the actual value.

Needless to say, the user of the Array module should not (need to) know about those implementation details, that is, the `AElem` type.

Comment: Thank you!
Just one thing 'derive ArrayElem AElem' should be'derive ArrayElement AElem' . ArrayElem is not 'deriveable'.